# Как вывести несколько чисел используя только SQL запрос?

Tags: sql

Нужно написать SQL запрос, который бы возвращал точно такой вывод:

```
id|
---
1 |
2 |
3 | 
5 |
```

Представьте, что в БД нет ни одной таблицы, и создавать их нельзя.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2 id UNION SELECT 3 id UNION SELECT 5 id;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  5 |
+----+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Существует ли более элегантное решение?

Comment: `order by` забыли.

Comment: В MySQL для 5 чисел более элегантного нет. Если чисел больше, то имеет смысл делать join из пары-тройки подобных запросов, для перемножения количества чисел. Более красивые решения доступны только в других СУБД поддерживающих например CTE. Единственное усовершенствование - `id` можно писать только у первого числа в union

Comment: ну почему же, есть процедуры

Comment: @splash58 Ну процедура это не совсем "sql-запрос", а ТС просит "написать SQL-запрос"

Comment: ну он один раз функцию  напишет, и будет ему запрос

Comment: хотя нет, извините соврамши, не будет ему запроса :)  но тем не менее

Comment: @Mike а ведь с одним алиасом - действительно более элегантно. Могли бы как ответ оформить)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В **MySQL** единственный вариант (Алиас нужен только у первого числа):

```
select 1 ID union select 2 union select 3 union select 5
```

Самый красивый (для малого количества чисел) вариант можно написать в **MS-SQL** и **Postrgess**:

```
select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(5)) as t(id)
```

**Oracle** (С использованием системного типа в качестве коллекции):

```
select column_value ID from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,5))
```

Если чисел значительно больше и они идут просто подряд, то почти универсальный (Из широко распространенных СУБД НЕ работает только в MySQL):

```
with Q as (
 select 1 ID 
  union all
 select ID+1 from Q where ID<5
) select * from Q
```

Самый лаконичный (IMHO) вариант для большого количества чисел подряд в **Oracle**:

```
select rownum id from DUAL connect by rownum<6
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой вариант, используя T-SQL.  Физически таблица не создается, так что условие выполнено) Плюс это решение намного более гибкое, если вдруг кто-то решит изменить задачу.

```
declare @t1 as table(ID int)

declare @i int=0

while (@i<5) begin

    set @i+=1
    if (@i<>4)
        insert into @t1
        values(@i)
end

select * from @t1
```

Comment: А про T-SQL речи не шло. И на MS-SQL без всяких переменных, именно "одним запросом" пишется `with Q as (
 select 1 ID
 union all select ID+1 from Q where ID<5
)
select * from Q  where ID!=4` И заодно работает на всех других СУБД поддерживающих CTE

Answer (score 2):

В *Oracle* ещё можно воспользоваться XQuery последовательностью:

```
select to_number(column_value) id from xmlTable ('1 to 3, 5')
/
        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         5
```